# Simple html dom error issue

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Well hello everybody,
In fact im working on a small php script that get a content from wikipedia rand pages this is the code that im using:

```
<?
include('dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B5:%D8%B9%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A');
foreach($html->find('h1#firstHeading') as $element) 
       echo $element->span->innertext . '<br>';
?>
```

but sometimes i get this error message:

> failed to open stream: Invalid redirect URL

I want the script to try many times until this error goes so he will be able to get the content from the random page.

Answer (score 0):

So this error is ok for you, since you generate random page url?

Than try `try catch`:

```
function getRandomUrl()
{
    include('dom.php');
    try {
        $html = file_get_html('http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B5:%D8%B9%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A');
        foreach($html->find('h1#firstHeading') as $element) {
            echo "{$element->span->innertext}<br/>";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        getRandomUrl();
    }
}
```

Also you can try run code without errors:

```
@file_get_html($randomUrl);
```

Comment: @user3756377 How do you know it's not working? Provide more info, not just "Nop, copy/paste does not work, find error for me, because i'm too lazy to say something more about it"

Comment: I see this error : 
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in

Comment: @user3756377 have you wrapped all your code inside `try - catch`, or just one line from answer?